# How to prevent js variables from being reset on reload in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, predix

I am trying to build a simple app on polymer using predix, the problem I am facing is:
   When the page reloads, the variables go back to their initial state, I am using those variables to show/hide content on navigation to other pages(.html files). I have one main .html file, where the variables are declared and has routes to all the files .

Questions:

1. What are the ways to prevent this?
2. How can I do this better as I am planning to build another bigger and complex application, which will require users logging in and out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any information you need to store on the client should be written in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). I personally prefer using [redux](https://github.com/tur-nr/polymer-redux) with my state stored in localStorage. With this my users can continue to work exactly where they stopped.
Athentication is something else you need to implement a Refresh Token mechanism like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token/current) is providing.

Comment: Alright, I went through the mentioned links, it seems very useful. I will try implementing it.
Thank you!

Comment: Good info from @pascal-l.  Also check out the Predix Webapp Starter as a starting point for you:  https://github.com/predixdev/predix-webapp-starter

Comment: Yes I have used that but I am following python folder structure because of the requirements @gstroup

Answer (score -1):

First of all, why do you need to reload the page or are you asking if for the reason that the user might reload the page? With polymer, it's a single view application, where the page should never reload and instead content is switched inside the current page.

That said, and because you asked for alternatives, you can also use your router to push to window.history and store the updated variables there.

```
window.history.pushState({'navigate': true, 'url': url, 'extra': extra}, 'FSport', url);

window.history.replaceState({'navigate': true, 'url': url, 'extra': extra}, 'FSport', url);
```

I don't know how the current router works in Polymer because we had to write our own router because that element didn't exist when we started using Polymer.

---

If you decide to go with saving in localStorage, also remember that you got indexDb for objects by using localforage. Even though it's slower than localStorage, you also got the benefit of handling promises (asynchronous data fetching).

Comment: Writing in the window is never a good Idea. Also persisting some kind of state is what redux does and there are redux addon´s that persist the state to the localStorage or IndexDB. Also having a Stateless WebComponent does not bite with having a single Page Application it just makes Dev Life just a lot nicer

Comment: You never said why writing in window is a bad idea.

Didn't know this was a pissing contest, and Harman asked about "ways" of doing something. I just gave an alternative. There is no right answer, just preferred ones, and if you want to downvote something because it's not your preferred answer, that's up to you.

Comment: Hey Rickard,
Thank you for your answer, I am new to polymer and I am figuring out things at a pace because I am bound by deadlines. 
It is the requirment of the backend and middleware that the application can not be SPA also it has to be on polymer and predix.
I am not reloading the app anywhere at all, this is in case the user presses the reload in browser.

I appreciate your answer and I will look into this as it seems like a fine idea to save my url as well as variable which will help restoring the session on reload.